# R programming - Age Function on a DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to build a function to calculate the age of some people whose year of birth is present in a this dataframe:

[image]

so I wrote this function:

```
    clceta <- function(x){
     i<-0
     age <- c()
     while(i <= length(x[, 2])){
           age[i] <- 2016 - x[i, 2]
           i <- i+1
     }
     x$eta <- age
    }
```

with it I calculate the actual age of people in data frame, and I save this information in a new df variable which should be `x$eta`, but when I run this function, giving the data frame as input it doesn't work. When I call the df there is no new variable on it, I still see the old one without the age varialbe. What did I do wrong?

To be more clear: when i use the function clceta() on my df "ut", the function caculates the age of each person in the df, using the formula 2016-ut$AnnoNascita, and creates the variable ut$eta in the df "ut", like this:

[[image: enter image description here[2]]

Comment: If you provide a small reproducible example and what the output would look like, perhaps we can help you with a more R-like solution.

Comment: A random guess: `ut$eta <- 2016 - ut$AnnoNascita`.

Comment: Why are you using a loop to calculate age?  Better to get the birth year and subtract it from the current year.  Your function will break next year.  You also need to look at the current month and day.  Wrong from beginning to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need for loop. Just one line.

```
ut$eta = 2016-ut$AnnoNascita
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop is unnecessary, you are simply subtracting the birth date from 2016 which can be done in one go to the whole column. Check out the following code:

```
# Create dataset for example
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, Birth = sample(1960:1990, 10))

# Add new column for age
data$Age <- 2016 - data[, "Birth"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x <- data.frame(eta = numeric(nrow(ut)))    
x$eta <- 2016 - as.numeric(ut$AnnoNascita)
```

Ah, OP changed his question, now its in ut not x, so this one line is enough and deals with the case where first col is not numeric:

```
ut$eta <- 2016 - as.numeric(ut$AnnoNascita)
```